# Postgis latitude/longitude read out reversed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, postgis

I have a class, Geocoordinateable, that gives models some useful methods for dealing with geo-coordinates. Included in this is "geocoordinates=" which accepts an array.

https://gist.github.com/mboyle/58dd3add830bbdeef316

You can call "geocoordinates" to get the coordinates in an array:

```
irb(main):056:0> b.geocoordinates
=> [-118.25, 34.197]
```

When I assign coordinates like so:

```
irb(main):058:0> b.geocoordinates = [34.197, -118.25]
   (1.8ms)  
 UPDATE users
 SET geocoordinates = 'SRID=4326;POINT(' || 34.197 || ' ' || -118.25 || ')'
 WHERE id = 347708

   (0.7ms)  
 UPDATE activities
 SET geocoordinates = users.geocoordinates
 FROM users
 WHERE activities.user_id = users.id
 AND users.id = 347708
 AND NOT postgis.ST_Equals(activities.geocoordinates, users.geocoordinates)

=> [34.197, -118.25]
```

Things seem to save and come out correctly. If I query the model again, however, and then read geocoordinates, the lat/long are reversed:

```
irb(main):059:0> b = User.find(b.id)
irb(main):060:0> b.geocoordinates
   (0.7ms)  
 SELECT postgis.ST_Y(geocoordinates) AS latitude, postgis.ST_X(geocoordinates) AS longitude
 FROM users
 WHERE id = 347708

=> [-118.25, 34.197]
```

I cannot for the life of me understand why this is happening. Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In PostGIS coordinates are set in (X, Y) order, or (longitude, latitude) for geographic coordinate pairs. So you should do:

```
UPDATE users
SET geocoordinates = 'SRID=4326;POINT(' || -118.25 || ' ' || 34.197 || ')'
WHERE id = 347708
```

and then probably too:

```
irb(main):058:0> b.geocoordinates = [-118.25, 34.197]
```

Note that PostGIS ingests text data in the Well-Known Text (WKT) format specified by the [OGC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text). The standard prescribes the (X,Y) or (lon,lat) order. So this is not something of a choice, it is required to enable PostGIS to ingest WKT files produced by other OGC-compliant software. After the WKT is ingested, PostGIS stores the data in its internal format, in fact a slightly modified OGC Well-Known Binary (WKB) format, in a column with the PostGIS-defined `geometry` or `geography` data type, and the data can then be analyzed and presented in any form desired by the end user.

Comment: actually, the output is (Y, X) -- (lat, lon), see the ruby SQL-Output: `SELECT postgis.ST_Y(geocoordinates) AS latitude, postgis.ST_X(geocoordinates) AS longitude`

Comment: @maze-le The output is indeed (lat, lon) because it is explicitly so requested with the PostGIS functions. The input, however, should be (lon, lat), at the very least in the `UPDATE` statement because that is how the WKT string ("SRID=4326;POINT(lon lat)") is interpreted. See an explanation in the updated answer.